# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found for the 'reading' role on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working on migrating our current Rails application(v 6.0.3.4) to a multi-tenant app where each client will have their own DB. The code works fine on my local environment but it gives `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:  No connection pool with 'primary' found for the 'reading' role` error on staging.

I'm selecting the DB at the rack level depending on the subdomain.

```
module Middlewares
  class Multitenancy
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end
 
    def call(env)
      @env = env
      
      database = { writing: "primary_#{subdomain}".to_sym, reading: "replica_reader_#{subdomain}".to_sym }
      

      ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: database) do
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end

    private

    def subdomain
       ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_subdomain(@env['HTTP_HOST'], 1) unless @env['HTTP_HOST'].nil?
    end
  end
end
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
#  reconnect: false
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_HOST") { '127.0.0.1' } %> # 127.0.0.1 to force use tcp ip instead of unix socket
  database:  <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_DB") { 'development' } %>
  pool:  <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } * 30 %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_USER") { 'root' } %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_PASSWORD") { '' } %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_PORT") { '3306' } %>
  variables:
    sql_mode: TRADITIONAL

staging:
  primary_subdomain_1:
    <<: *default
    host: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_HOST") %>
  replica_reader_subdomain_1:
    <<: *default
    host: <%= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_HOST_REPLICA") %>
    replica: true
  primary_subdomain_2:
    <<: *default
    host: %= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_HOST2") %>
  replica_reader_subdomain_2:
    <<: *default
    host: %= ENV.fetch("MYSQL_HOST2_REPLICA") %>
    replica: true
``
```

Comment: is there anywhere in your code that connect to db with role `:reading` such as `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do ...` ?

Comment: No, we don't use the above anywhere in our application.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was rails' [automatic connection switching](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#activating-automatic-connection-switching).

I commented the lines below in `config/environments/staging.rb` and it worked.

```
config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
```

Comment: Doesn't this disable automatic switching though?